# how to schedule a notification using alarm manager

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-alarms

I have defined a receiver which should fire the notification when it is called. This works only if I call the receiver straight away.
I am unable to schedule it for a specific date.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(2014, 4, 18, 2, 20, 0);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(getBaseContext().ALARM_SERVICE);
int id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
Intent intent = new Intent(this, TimeAlarm.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);   
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

This is my Receiver class:

```
public class TimeAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent paramIntent) {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW");
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.sdfasdf.ch"));
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    // Create the notification
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.android_anydont_logo, "sdfs", System.currentTimeMillis());
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "something something", "darkside",pendingIntent);

    // Fire the notification
    notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
}
}
```

This is the definition in the manifest:

```
receiver
        android:name="com.hack.doneit.utils.TimeAlarm"
        android:process=":remote" />
```

My problem is that i am unable to set the alarm to trigger the receiver at a specific time in the future. A specific day would be enough.

Comment: Does my answer worked ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with the `Month` value you have set. I believe you thought for month `April` the value is 4. The value of month `starts from 0` , so `April will be 3`.

Change you code on month as `Calendar.APRIL` or set value as `3`

```
c.set(2014, Calendar.APRIL, 17, 20, 43, 0);
```

This should work. Apart from this your codes are perfect.

Note: Your using the `Notification` deprecated API's . Use `Notification Builder`